# Porque me salta error en el string? Algo mal definido?

Tags: php

Adjunto parte del codigo:

**la version de php es 8.0.9**

Los arrastro de un input:

```
<input type="number" id="p17" name="p17" min="1" max="5" placeholder="1-5"><br>
```

**se declaran las variables**

```
$comparar_sql = "SELECT id_A,id_B,fecha,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30,p31,p32,comentarios FROM form WHERE id_A = '$VA' and id_B = '$VB'";
$comp = mysqli_query($con,$comparar_sql);

if($comp)
{
while($row = $comp->fetch_array())
{
$EVA = $row['id_A'];
$EVAL = $row['id_B'];
$F = $row['fecha'];
$p1 = $row['p1'];
$p2 = $row['p2'];
$p3 = $row['p3'];
$p4 = $row['p4'];
$p5 = $row['p5'];
$p6 = $row['p6'];
$p7 = $row['p7'];
$p8 = $row['p8'];
$p9 = $row['p9'];
$p10 = $row['p10'];
$p11 = $row['p11'];
$p12 = $row['p12'];
$p13 = $row['p13'];
$p14 = $row['p14'];
$p15 = $row['p14'];
$p16 = $row['p15'];
$p17 = $row['p16'];
$p18 = $row['p17'];
$p19 = $row['p18'];
$p20 = $row['p19'];
$p21 = $row['p21'];
$p22 = $row['p22'];
$p23 = $row['p23'];
$p24 = $row['p24'];
$p25 = $row['p25'];
$p26 = $row['p26'];
$p27 = $row['p27'];
$p28 = $row['p28'];
$p29 = $row['p29'];
$p30 = $row['p30'];
$p31 = $row['p31'];
$p32 = $row['p32'];
$comen = $row['comentarios'];
}
}
```

**llamo la variable getexp**

```
<?php

require_once('mpdf/vendor/autoload.php');

//Html Tabla 
require_once('tablap.php');

//css
$css = file_get_contents('sty_tabla.css');

//base de datos
require_once('basedatos.php');

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf
([
'format' => 'Legal'
]);

$Exp = getExp
(
$F,
$Acedula,
$Anombre,
$Agrupo,
$Acargo,
$Bcedula,
$Bnombre,
$Bcargo,
$p1,
$p2,
$p3,
$p4,
$p5,
$p6,
$p7,
$p8,
$p9,
$p10,
$p11,
$p12,
$p13,
$p14,
$p15,
$p16,
$p17,
$p18,
$p19,
$p20,
$p21,
$p22,
$p23,
$p24,
$p25,
$p26,
$p27,
$p28,
$p29,
$p30,
$p31,
$p32,
$comen
);

$mpdf->writeHtml($css,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->writeHtml($Exp,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);

$mpdf->Output("EVALUACION DE DESEMPEÑO.pdf","I");
```

Aqui las declaro o las llamo.

```
function getExp
(
$F,
$Acedula,
$Anombre,
$Agrupo,
$Acargo,
$Bcedula,
$Bnombre,
$Bcargo,
$p1,
$p2,
$p3,
$p4,
$p5,
$p6,
$p7,
$p8,
$p9,
$p10,
$p11,
$p12,
$p13,
$p14,
$p15,
$p16,
$p17,
$p18,
$p19,
$p20,
$p21,
$p22,
$p23,
$p24,
$p25,
$p26,
$p27,
$p28,
$p29,
$p30,
$p31,
$p32,
$comen
)
```

tabla.php

```
    <td colspan=2 height=45 class=xl716105 width=589 style="border-right:1.0pt solid black;
  height:33.75pt;width:442pt">Conoce y cumple los procedimientos establecidos
  para el cargo correspondiente</td>
  <td class=xl1316105 width=145 style="border-top:none;border-left:none;
  width:109pt">'.$p17.'</td>
  <td rowspan=2 class=xl736105 width=145 style="border-bottom:1.0pt solid black;
  border-top:none;width:109pt">'.(($p17+$p18)/2).'</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=62 style="mso-height-source:userset;height:46.5pt">
  <td colspan=2 height=62 class=xl746105 width=589 style="border-right:1.0pt solid black;
  height:46.5pt;width:442pt">Lleva un registro de los procedimientos
  realizados, para no generar repeticiones, errores o inconformidades</td>
  <td class=xl1326105 width=145 style="border-left:none;width:109pt">'.$p18.'</td>
 </tr>
```

Y el error que bota es el siguiente.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\PDF\tablap.php:138 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\PDF\mpdf.php(65):
> getExp('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\PDF\tablap.php on line 138``

Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En el código que tengo en esa linea, aparece error, todo esta adjunto a unas comillas sencillas, exceptuando la suma.

Comment: Por este tipo de preguntas es que uno les dice que pongan la versión del software que están usando. ¿Quieres concatenar esas dos variables o sumar su contenido? ¿PHP8, cierto?

Comment: `$p17` y `$p18` son dos cadenas, si quieres efectuar una operacón de suma deberás declararlas o convertirlas a valores numéricos. El mensaje de error te lo está diciendo muy claramente: *`Unsupported operand types: string + string`*

Comment: @A.Cedano ya estan declaradas al inicio de esa parte del codigo en un fuction

Comment: ¿Declaradas cómo (qué tipo de dato)? Muestra ese código que refieres. Si las debes sumar deben ser declaradas de un tipo numérico.

Comment: No agregues más cosas en el área de respuestas. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar nuevo contenido a la pregunta. Lo que debes mostrar es la parte donde defines tus variables problemáticas.

Comment: Lo siento, no entiendo muy bien este foro, pero necesito la ayuda

Comment: Si las variables `$p17` y `$p18` son números, conviene que las declares como tales en la definición de la función, haciendo algo así: `function getExp
(string $F, string $Acedula, string $Anombre, int $p17, int $p18, ... etc ...)`  Conviene que uses la declaración de tipos en todos tus parámetros. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php) al respecto. En el ejemplo he asumido que las primeras tres son cadenas (`string`) y que las otras son enteros, si son decimales debes declararlas como `float` en vez de `int`. completa la función definiendo cada tipo.

Comment: Exactamente... @A. Cedano

Comment: Coloca el código donde llamas a `getExp()` para poder ayudarte mejor. Si estás usando PHP 7 o superior conviene que escribas un código correctamente tipado, de lo contrario estarás arrastrando prácticas de versiones antiguas de PHP convirtiendo los datos una y otra vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano Coloco el llamado, ahi mismo en la pregunta?

Comment: Sí, edita la pregunta y agrega el código donde recoges los parámetros y llamas a la función pasándole esos parámetros.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo, ya la edite

Comment: No veo donde declaras todas las variables que pasas en parámetro a la función que es lo que interesa aquí. Las recoges de `$_POST` o de `$_GET`  supongo, pues dices que las tomas de un formulario. Muestra el código donde creas las variales.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo

Comment: Entonces las variables no vienen de un formulario como decías al principio, sino de una consulta a la base de datos ¿? Aclara ese punto porque estamos hablando de algo nuevo en PHP que es escribir un código tipado y, sea que los datos vengan de una BD o de un formulario, hay formas óptimas de conservar sus tipos para no tener que definirlos de nuevo a mano o convertirlos de forma mediocre. O sea, podrías usar `MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE` o filtros, según los datos vengan de un lado o del otro.

Comment: @A.Cedano y esa variable en que parte del codigo podria ponerla ?

Comment: La explicación no cabía en un comentario así que, revisa la respuesta. Si tienes alguna duda comenta debajo de la respuesta dada.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, falta código para entender la pregunta.

Tienes dos variables llamadas `$p17` y `$p17` que no se muestran en tu pregunta...

Como tu error dice `Unsupported operand types: string + string` intentas hacer una operación aritmética no permitida, estas intentando sumar los valores de dos string...

Si quieres hacer esto tienes que transformar las variables de cadena (string) a un numero entero (int) utilizando `intval($p17)` y `intval($p18)`.

(`intval(X)` se utiliza para convertir el valor de un String a entero)

Por ejemplo, imaginimos que `$p17 = '2'` y `$p18 = '2'` y quieres obtener la suma de estos valores entre /2. Para esta operación tu codigo quedaria tal que así:

```
$p17 = '2';
$p18 = '2';

echo intval($p17)+intval($p18) /2;

?>
```

Solo tienes que aplicarlo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Y la próxima vez asegúrate de publicar el código necesario para que cualquier persona pueda entender tu problema y encontrar una solución...

Comment: Si tienes alguna pregunta escribe un comentario.

Comment: Mas o menos entiendo a lo que te referiste y dijiste, pero las variables `$p17` y `$18` las arrastro de un <input>

Comment: Tu problema es que el valor que almacenas en tus variables que arrastras del <input> son almacenadas como String y intentas sumarlas, cosa que no puedes hacer, por eso mismo tienes que convertir primero de string a int utilizando `intval(tuVariable)`

Comment: De todas formas, como te a comentado el usuario @A. Cedano, en tu función `getExp` deberias declarar las variables según su tipo.

Answer (score 1):

El error es debido a que intentas sumar dos valores que en su origen son cadenas (string).

Desde su versión 7 en adelante PHP empezó a preocuparse seriamente por la declaración de tipos, lo cual es un gran avance porque PHP fue demasiado permisivo en el pasado.

Para adaptar tu código a un PHP moderno, te recomiendo que te preocupes muy seriamente de los tipos de datos que estás manejando, usando según cada contexto las herramientas disponibles para ello.

Para resolver tu problema según el espíritu de PHP 7+ conviene hacer dos cosas:

1. Indicar en tu función de qué tipo es cada dato. Dado que es una función enorme, en la respuesta te pondré sólo algunos ejemplos, te tocará a ti completar la función indicando para cada parámetro su tipo respectivo (para ver los posibles tipos de datos [consulta el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.declarations.php)).
2. En el contexto donde obtienes los datos que pasas a la función, preocuparte porque ya ahí cada dato se genere con su respectivo tipo.

   Esto dependerá de dónde vienen los datos, de qué tipo son en su fuente y de otras cosas... Por ejemplo, si los datos vienen de una base de datos, si usas la API `mysqli` y los datos numéricos son del tipo correcto (`INT`, `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT`...) podrás usar la opción [`MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.options.php) para configurar la API de forma que garantice que la consulta te arroje los datos respetando sus tipos. Cabe decir que esta opción sólo funciona si tienes instalado el controlador `mysqlnd`. En su defecto, deberás indicar el tipo al crear cada variable. Si usas PDO es otra historia. Y si los datos vienen de un formulario, podrás usar [`filter_input_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input-array.php) (ver **Ejemplo 1**) para garantizar el tipado de una forma segura, aplicando además filtros en los datos, práctica totalmente recomendable para estos casos.

   Lo importante aquí es comprender que para cada caso existen soluciones óptimas, modernas y seguras que deberías implementar, evitando soluciones a mano cuano esto sea posible.

### Soluciones propuestas

Aplicando lo dicho anteriormente, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

Definimos la función indicando para cada parámetro su tipo:

```
function getExp(
 string $F,
 string $Acedula,
 string $Anombre,
 string $Agrupo,
 string $Acargo,
 string $Bcedula,
 string $Bnombre,
 string $Bcargo,
 int $p1,
 int $p2,
 /*... completar cada parámetro poniendo el tipo adecuado ... */
)
{
    /*Cuerpo de la función*/
}
```

Ahora, en el contexto de la función, aseguramos el tipado.

Si tienes `mysqlnd` y los datos en la base de datos están definidos correctamente, basta con esto:

```
/*
   Esto asegura que se respetarán los tipos de cada columna
   y cada variable será del tipo adecuado sin necesidad de nada más
*/
$con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true); 
$comparar_sql = "SELECT ...";
$comp = mysqli_query($con,$comparar_sql);

if($comp)
{
while($row = $comp->fetch_array())
{
$EVA = $row['id_A'];
$EVAL = $row['id_B'];
$F = $row['fecha'];
$p1 = $row['p1'];
$p2 = $row['p2'];
$p3 = $row['p3'];
$p4 = $row['p4'];
$p5 = $row['p5'];
$p6 = $row['p6'];
$p7 = $row['p7'];
$p8 = $row['p8'];
$p9 = $row['p9'];
$p10 = $row['p10'];
$p11 = $row['p11'];
$p12 = $row['p12'];
$p13 = $row['p13'];
$p14 = $row['p14'];
$p15 = $row['p14'];
$p16 = $row['p15'];
$p17 = $row['p16'];
$p18 = $row['p17'];
$p19 = $row['p18'];
$p20 = $row['p19'];
$p21 = $row['p21'];
$p22 = $row['p22'];
$p23 = $row['p23'];
$p24 = $row['p24'];
$p25 = $row['p25'];
$p26 = $row['p26'];
$p27 = $row['p27'];
$p28 = $row['p28'];
$p29 = $row['p29'];
$p30 = $row['p30'];
$p31 = $row['p31'];
$p32 = $row['p32'];
$comen = $row['comentarios'];
}
}
```

Si no tienes `mysqlnd` o los tipos no han sido respetados al diseñar la tabla, deberás tipar a mano cada variable:

```
$comparar_sql = "SELECT ...";
$comp = mysqli_query($con,$comparar_sql);

if($comp)
{
while($row = $comp->fetch_array())
{
(string) $EVA = $row['id_A'];
(string) $EVAL = $row['id_B'];
(string) $F = $row['fecha'];
(int) $p1 = $row['p1'];
(int) $p2 = $row['p2'];
/*Completar cada tipo*/
}
}
```

Si las variables vienen en una super global desde un formulario eso ya es otra historia, pero debes saber que para esos casos también hay formas óptimas para filtrar tipar que deberías implementar si lo necesitaras.

Comment: Perdon la ignorancia, hasta ahora empiezo con todo esto, pero como se si tengo mysqlnd ?

Comment: @Roberto puedes saberlo verificando si una de las funciones propias de ese controlador existe, por ejemplo, si `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all'));`  te arroja `true` es que lo tienes, y si arroja `false` no lo tienes o no está activado.